# Google Apps Script and Google Search Console API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-search-console, urlfetch

I need to access datas from Search Console using Apps Script.
I tried a loads of things but nothing worked.
I'm using this doc : https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/searchanalytics/query

Here are some things I tried :

```
function authenticate() {
return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
    .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly"})
    .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
          function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); })}


function loadClient() {
gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
return gapi.client.load("https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/searchconsole/v1/rest")
    .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
          function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); })}


function execute() {
return gapi.client.webmasters.searchanalytics.query({
  "resource": {}
})
    .then(function(response) {
            // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
            console.log("Response", response);
          },
          function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); })}
```

Other try:

```
function searchConsoleQuery() {
  var service = getService();

  var apiURL = 
     'https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/[SITE_URL]/searchAnalytics/query';

  var headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken(),
'contentType':'application/json',
'startDate':'20019-10-01',
'endDate':'2019-10-10'};

 var options = {
'payload': JSON.stringify(headers),
'method' : 'POST',
'muteHttpExceptions': true};

 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL, options);

 var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
 Logger.log(json)}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `headers` is used to `payload`.
- `'startDate'` is `20019-10-01`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function searchConsoleQuery() {
  var siteUrl = "###"; // Please set your site URL.

  var service = getService();
  var apiURL = `https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/${encodeURIComponent(siteUrl)}/searchAnalytics/query`;
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'headers': { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken() },
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload': JSON.stringify({
      'startDate': '2019-10-01',
      'endDate': '2019-10-10'
    })
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL, options);
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(json)
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that Google Search Console API has already been enabled at API console and also `siteUrl` and your access token of `service.getAccessToken()` are the valid values for using the API. Please be careful about this. When I tested this modified script with my site URL, I confirmed that the values are returned without error. So, if an error occurs, please confirm the condition of API in your API console and your values again.
- If no values are returned, please modify `'startDate': '2019-10-01'` and `'endDate': '2019-10-10'` and test it again.

#### References:

- [Search Analytics: query](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/searchanalytics/query)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)